# How to set the <img> tag with basic authentication

Tags: html, authentication, image

I would like to display the image from a network camera on my web page, but the image is behind a HTTP basic authentication server.

In Firefox and Chrome I can do this:

```
<img width="320" height="200" src="http://username:password@server/Path" />
```

But in Internet Explorer 8, I get an empty image box.  If I use JQuery to set the src attribute, IE8 displays a blank src.  It looks like IE8 is checking the string and rejecting it.

Is there a way to put the basic authentication credentials in the img tag?

Comment: Wouldn't it be unsafe to do that? The tag is visible to everyone.

Comment: Before the user can get to this HTML file, he would have to get through a log in page.

Comment: I get it, I thought it will work like, the user will visit the page, to login. lol.

Comment: Did you end up using the proxy method? I'm having the same problem and I can't find a solution anywhere

Comment: I just ran into this issue. I solved it using [user3053216's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042994/how-to-show-an-image-which-is-secured-by-http-authentication) which does what I think Spudley is suggesting below, but it provides a code example to explain how to do it.

Comment: Got the same issue in Chrome, version 58 lol.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bottom line: Not all browsers allow this. It may work in some but not others.

But as someone else has said already, it's not very safe -- you're effectively giving the login and password details to anyone who browses the page. Not good.

A better option would be proxy it through the same server that you're providing the html code from, then the href in the `<img>` tag could just be a local URL, and no-one need know where the image is actually coming from.

Comment: "Not all browsers allow this. It may work in some but not others."  Can you cite your source?

Comment: @Robert - no source; just experience; I had a similar frustration to you some time ago, trying something very similar.  :)  But that said, I may be out of date as I haven't actually tried doing this sort of thing for quite a while, due to my other point; ie it's not very safe.

Comment: also, to clarify: there's a difference in how browsers will treat it if you enter `name:password@server/path` in the address bar, vs if it's in a link. Because passwords are involved, the browser's security policy comes into play.

Answer (score 5):

You can load your `img` with AJAX, using [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/). As you might know, XMLHttpRequest has a `setRequestHeaders` method, so you will be able to manipulate headers for your request, hence, you will be able to do basic HTTP authentication.

Comment: You can pass auth info in parameters to `open()`. Unfortunately extracting the binary content of a response, and injecting it into an image node on the page, isn't so easy.

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to create a login page, then setup port forwarding on your router to display the camera.  Does the camera come with web software?

Answer (score 1):

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489 and [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330735(v=vs.85).aspx#login_creds_urls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#login_creds_urls)

Long story short, usernames/passwords are not formally supported under the HTTP/HTTPS protocol schemes and due to their use in phishing attacks, they were disabled in IE6 on XPSP2. Support can be manually re-enabled by the user using a registry override (`FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE`) but this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try http proxy.

On server side, enable tinyProxy, create `ReversePath` to
basic authentication server in configuration like:

```
AddHeader "Authorization" "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz"
ReversePath "/foo/" "http://somewhere:3480/foo/"
```

`dXNlcjpwYXNz` is base64 encoded string from `user:pass`

Enable reverse proxy in Apache or NGINX to tinyProxy path http://localhot:8888/foo/

Img Source accessable from local server instead of old way deprecated, without http auth pop-up or CORS error.

```
http://user:pass@somewhere:3480/foo/DEST.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax add http header works!

```
pictureUrl = "https://somewhere/file.jpg";
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", pictureUrl, true);
oReq.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("UserName"+":"+"Password"));
// use multiple setRequestHeader calls to set multiple values
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  var arrayBuffer = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
  if (arrayBuffer) {
    var u8 = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    var b64encoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, u8));
    var mimetype="image/jpeg"; // or whatever your image mime type is
    document.getElementById("iOdata").src="data:"+mimetype+";base64,"+b64encoded;
  }
};
oReq.send(null);
```