# How to show an image which is secured by http authentication

Tags: php, html, image, http-authentication

How can i show an image from a server with standard http protection without showing the authentication window?

I now use standard html

```
<img src="...">
```

but because the image is protected this asks for an authentication window. I do have the login data, how can i show the image?

Regards, Tom.

Comment: You should provide some code.

Comment: Are you able to use PHP at all? If not, please ignore this comment. If so, I would suggest using a php script as a proxy and using cURL with basic auth ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl ) to read the image from the remote location.   Then set the header-content type to whatever the image type is.  For instance for JPEG: header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); I use this mechanism often.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used IrishGeeks tip to get a solution. It works on all browsers. The script.php is

```
<?php
$url    = $_GET['url'];
$c = curl_init($url);
$authString = 'user:pass';
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $authString);

$content = curl_exec($c);
$contentType = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
header('Content-Type:'.$contentType);
print $content;
?>
```

Then use

```
<?php
print '<img src="script.php?url='.urlencode('http://www.example.com/image.bmp').'" />';
?>
```

To get the image.

Comment: I'm shocked that this code was the accepted answer to this question. While your script makes it possible to load images through htaccess-protected websites it leaves your website open to a bunch of attacks including XSS-Injections. You are using the Content Type from the given Website, and there isnt any check for malicious content or something. I wont mind how much websites are vulnarable bc they are copying this code here and doesnt mind about how its working. Please edit it and stop spreading insecure code.

Answer (score 7):

This should work. Simply replace the username and password with your authentication details. (Warning: Doesn't work in all browsers)

```
<img src="http://username:password@server/Path" />
```

I would recommend putting this in a separate file on your server. That way you can reference it without exposing the authentication info.