# consuming authenticated webapi in img tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a webAPI that is serving images.

```
http://{uri}/Data/api/v1/ImageData?objectType=1&dbKey=12
```

I am trying to consume it in `<img>` tag dynamically in c# like this:

```
 var src = string.Format("http://{uri}/Data/api/v1/ImageData?objectType={0}&dbKey={1}", viewType, dbKey);

 html.Append(@"<div class='Image'>");
 html.AppendFormat(@"<span><img src ='{0}'/></span>", src);
 html.Append(@"</div>");
```

Now, the issue I run into is that I webAPI has a basic authentication that I need to pass a user name and password. How can I do that? unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823357/how-to-set-the-img-tag-with-basic-authentication) question, I am trying to find better way to pass username and password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the <img> tag with basic authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823357/how-to-set-the-img-tag-with-basic-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

If it's your API, then I would consider switching to a [token based authentication](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/), which is something that you can pass in a cookie (Or get variable).

It's not currently possible to pass user/password data through an image tag that's agnostic across all browsers.