# Ionic img basic authentication

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can I set basic authentication on IMG tag for Ionic?

I have tried using `src="http://username:password@server/Path"` as suggested on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823357/how-to-set-the-img-tag-with-basic-authentication) which works fine with `ionic serve` in browser, but when uploaded to mobile it doesn't work. I am fetching other resources with authentication header with http request which works fine also.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you whitelisted something like http ://username*/*"? The fact that it works on a browser but not on a device would indicate it's a whitelist problem.

Comment: Not really...I tried installing cordova whitelist plugin, but it doesn't help

Comment: It doesn't help if you just install it. Have you looked at the logs if there's any errors/messages which could be related to this issue?

Comment: I didn't just install it, I have also added that line of code to config.xml. Where can I see the logs when using phone?

Comment: Have you also looked at the Content Security Policy statements? And if you're running an android device you can connect it to your computer and navigate to chrome://inspect/#devices with a Chrome browser to open your application in a tab and see all sorts of stuff, including the logs.