# Not asked to authorize when trying to access protected videostream in <img />- tag = 403

Tags: html, vuejs2, http-status-code-403, ip-camera

I'm trying to fetch a live stream from my IP-camera and display it in a image tag in my Vuejs project:

```
<img src="http://10.0.0.110/video1.mjpg">
```

(nothing special here)

`http://10.0.0.110/video1.mjpg` is a protected resource and not accessible for unauthorized users. If I put `http://10.0.0.110/video1.mjpg` in my browser's address field, I will correctly be asked for credentials (just as it should be).

#### Problem:

My problem is that I am not asked for any credentials when I'm browsing my `html` containing this: `<img src="http://10.0.0.110/video1.mjpg">`. I'm left with an adequate error message in my browser's inspector:
[image: my browser's inspector]

#### Question:

Is it possible to force the browswer to ask for credentials? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is a duplicate of [How to set the <img> tag with basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823357/how-to-set-the-img-tag-with-basic-authentication)

The accepted answer may indicate that this is not possible. I was able to reproduce your issue. I tried a little bit myself and ended up using an iframe.  Try something like `<iframe src="http://10.0.0.110/video1.mjpg"></iframe>` and set an appropriate size. It worked for me in Chrome.

Comment: You are right. That question was very similar to mine. Your workaround is good for me!